# Joining dictionaries to make a table

Tags: kdb

I get a table when I join the dictionaries with same keys :

```
q)((`s`p!`s1`p1);(`s`p!`s2`p2))

s  p 
-----
s1 p1
s2 p2
```

But if keys are different it just returns the list, is there a way to generate a proper table?

```
q)((`s`p!`s1`p1);(`s`p`m!`s2`p2`m2))

`s`p!`s1`p1
`s`p`m!`s2`p2`m2
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `uj` along with adverb `over` to get the table:

```
q)(uj)over enlist each ((`s`p!`s1`p1);(`s`p`m!`s2`p2`m2))

s  p  m 
--------
s1 p1   
s2 p2 m2
```

Please note that we first made the individual dictionary to table before joining.

The `over` is particularly useful when there are more than 2 dictionaries. 
Otherwise using `uj` alone can do the trick.

```
q)(enlist `s`p!`s1`p1) uj (enlist `s`p`m!`s2`p2`m2)

s  p  m 
--------
s1 p1   
s2 p2 m2
```

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to use take `#` to make the keys of the dictionaries uniform

```
q)`s`p`m#/:((`s`p!`s1`p1);(`s`p`m!`s2`p2`m2))
s  p  m
--------
s1 p1
s2 p2 m2
```

If you need to, you can use something like `(union/) key each` to combine the keys of all the dictionaries into a list of unique keys

```
q)((union/)key each d)#/:d:((`s`p!`s1`p1);(`s`p`m!`s2`p2`m2))
s  p  m
--------
s1 p1
s2 p2 m2
```

Comparing execution time & memory usage of the different options

```
q)\ts:1000 (uj)over enlist each ((`s`p!`s1`p1);(`s`p`m!`s2`p2`m2))
53 2288
q)\ts:1000 `s`p`m#/:((`s`p!`s1`p1);(`s`p`m!`s2`p2`m2))  
13 1920
q)\ts:1000 ((union/)key each d)#/:d:((`s`p!`s1`p1);(`s`p`m!`s2`p2`m2))
22 2880
```

So most efficient is of course if you know all the possible keys. But it's still a good bit faster to use `#` if you just want to use all keys from the list of dictionaries as well

Comment: The issue here though is that take (#) is not going to know what datatype to conform to. It just so happens that in this example all the datatypes are symbol and so the datatypes conform. If you had something like `s`p`m#/:((`s`p!`s1`p1);(`s`p`m!(`s2;`s3;1i))) then the "m" in the first dictionary will not have the same type as the "m" in the second dictionary except by chance. The uj method will create uniform datatype where possible